# Is ubuntu 9.04 good choice for embedded linux application development?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, embedded, ubuntu-9.04, embedded-linux

I want to change linux distro my Development(Host) Machine which I use for embedded development.

I cross-compile applications for many different processors. It is required for me to download different different libraries to evaluate their functionality/Performance/Stability on different devices , as well as on PC.

So Is ubuntu 9.04 a good choice for me?

Thanks,
  Sunny.

Comment: I suppose that'd depend on what you're embedding it on.

Comment: I think you are asking which OS for the host development system, right?

Comment: Yes. I am asking for host development.

Comment: Question wording is confusing—not obvious on first read that you're talking about an OS for the PC, not the embedded device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gcc or other source based compiler that runs on linux then I would say yes, you want a linux distro, and ubuntu is currently the most popular/best.  I would try to avoid distro specific things, drive down the middle of the road and you should be able to use any distro equally well.

Answer (score 1):

That will largely depend on your needs. For an embedded system, I'd go with [any distribution](http://www.linuxlinks.com/Embedded/Distributions/) that sports a very small footprint and supports the necessary hardware.

Depending on your hardware, [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) might work fine.  You could create your image with [debootstrap](http://packages.qa.debian.org/d/debootstrap.html) which allows for fairly small customized installs. It still includes apt and other things which might not be desirable, although that could be to your benefit if you need to push out updates.

If you did go with Debian, you could most likely do all your development on Ubuntu and then push to your embedded system.

Comment: Debian suits embedded projects quite well; http://emdebian.org/ squeezes it down even further.

Answer (score 1):

i use ubuntu for my host system and a chrooted gentoo install for building apps for an embedded target.  I found gentoo was a good choice as it is source distributed and easy to select what version of a particular library is installed.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is good to know is that ubuntu and derivatives uses dash and not bash as /bin/sh. This confuses crosstools and can give you severe headaches.